# eli5: show_weights() with two labels

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, regression

I'm trying [eli5](http://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/eli5.html#eli5.show_prediction) in order to understand the contribution of terms to the prediction of certain classes.

**You can run this script:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

#categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian']
categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian', 'comp.graphics']

np.random.seed(1)
train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories, shuffle=True, random_state=7)
test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', categories=categories, shuffle=True, random_state=7)

bow_model = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
clf = LogisticRegression()
pipel = Pipeline([('bow', bow),
                 ('classifier', clf)])

pipel.fit(train.data, train.target)

import eli5
eli5.show_weights(clf, vec=bow, top=20)
```

**Problem:**

When working with two labels, the output is unfortunately limited to only one table:

```
categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian']
```

[image: Image 1]

However, when using three labels, it also outputs three tables.

```
categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian', 'comp.graphics']
```

[image]

*Is it a bug in the software that it misses y=0 in the first output, or do I miss a statistical point?* I would expect to see two tables for the first case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has not to do with eli5 but with how scikit-learn (in this case `LogisticRegression()`) treats two categories. For only two categories, the problem turns into a binary one, so only a single column of attributes is returned everywhere from learned classifier.

Look at the attributes of LogisticRegression:

> coef_ : array, shape (1, n_features) or (n_classes, n_features)
>
> ```
> Coefficient of the features in the decision function.
> coef_ is of shape (1, n_features) when the given problem is binary.
> ```
>
> intercept_ : array, shape (1,) or (n_classes,)
>
> ```
> Intercept (a.k.a. bias) added to the decision function.
>
> If fit_intercept is set to False, the intercept is set to zero.
> intercept_ is of shape(1,) when the problem is binary.
> ```

`coef_` is of shape `(1, n_features)` when binary. This `coef_` is used by the `eli5.show_weights()`.

Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Basically, there is no way to have an output for two classes then? Because I would have expected that both classes each have positive and negative loading factors?

Comment: @Christopher The positive weights for one class become the negatives for other class. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: In this logic, why is it then three tables for case #2? Why not two tables?

Comment: @Christopher Because multi-class cases are handled as one-vs-rest, where the problem is divided into 3 binary problems. One for each class. [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest)

Comment: how can I change the printed column name from `Weights` to `Scores` for example?

Comment: How can I get the `eli5.show_weights()` into a python array variable for re-use without showing this table/diagram?

Comment: @JananathBanuka Maybe you need the `coef_` from the trained model.