# Eli5 explain_weights does not returns feature_importance for each class with sklearn Random Forest classifier

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I am using the `eli5` `explain_weights` function on a Random Forest classifier from scikit-learn. I have seen in the eli5 [documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/eli5/downloads/pdf/latest/) (pp. 30-31) that this function is able to return feature importance (mean weight + standard deviation) **for each class** to predict. However, when using it on my dataset, the function only returns feature importances **for the whole model** (not for each class).

Here a reproductible example generated with the `scikit-learn make_classification` function:

```
import pandas as pd
import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

x, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=200, n_features=5, n_informative=3, n_redundant=2, n_classes=4)
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['feat_1', 'feat_2', 'feat_3', 'feat_4', 'feat_5']), pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['classe'])], axis=1)
df = df.replace({'classe': {0: '1st', 1: '2nd', 2: '3rd', 3: '4th'}})

labels = pd.unique(df['classe'])

train, test = train_test_split(df, stratify=df['classe'], test_size=0.40)

rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(train[['feat_1', 'feat_2', 'feat_3', 'feat_4', 'feat_5']], train['classe'])

perm = PermutationImportance(rf).fit(test[['feat_1', 'feat_2', 'feat_3', 'feat_4', 'feat_5']], test['classe'])
var_imp_classes = eli5.explain_weights(perm, top=5, targets=labels, target_names=labels, feature_names=['feat_1', 'feat_2', 'feat_3', 'feat_4', 'feat_5'])

print(eli5.format_as_text(var_imp_classes))
```

I have renamed features and classes but this is not mandatory here. Likewise, the `PermutationImportance` step can be avoided by replacing the `perm` argument in `eli5.explain_weights` by `rf`.

This code returns the following:

```
Explained as: feature importances

Feature importances, computed as a decrease in score when feature
values are permuted (i.e. become noise). This is also known as 
permutation importance.

If feature importances are computed on the same data as used for training, 
they don't reflect importance of features for generalization. Use a held-out
dataset if you want generalization feature importances.

0.3475 ± 0.1111  feat_1
0.1900 ± 0.1134  feat_4
0.0700 ± 0.0200  feat_3
0.0550 ± 0.0624  feat_2
0.0300 ± 0.0300  feat_5
```

I can't find the detailed result for each class, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659523/eli5-show-weights-with-two-labels). I am using the `explain_weights`the `show_weights` function as I would like to store the output in a DataFrame, but the same issue arises when using `show_weights`. I have the same issue using other classifiers, such as `SGDClassifier`, and after removing the `PermutationImportance` step.

What is wrong with my code?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything's wrong with your code 
In the example you gave ELI5 was giving explanation for each class because it was used on a Logistic Regression model, which has separate regression coefficients for each class. 
This does not happen in Random Forest - in particular if you use Permutation Importances. These are simply the decrease in accuracy of your model when predicting with a given permuted variable, so there's just one per model and not one per class. One could consider the decrease in classification accuracy for every class - these might give a general idea but I am not sure that they would be consistent.

If you really need to know which variables are most distinctive for each category, you can maybe run K (given that you have K classes) separate one-vs-the-rest binary classification RFs, and use those permutation importances as your indicators.